# Three phase induction motor 3

Tags: motor, induction-motor, resonance

For most common/casual 3 phase induction motor, If we connect proper capacitors in series or parallel, can we get resonance like LC circuit ?
thank a lot. star or delta . doesnt matter.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain in more detail the context of this question. Do you expect a "Yes" or "No" only answer or are you hoping for more detail? Please capitalise an punctuate properly for legibility and credibility.

Comment: Your edit is a small improvement but there is still no context and you didn't tidy up. (1) What are "proper capacitors"? (2) Are you aware that parallel capacitors are used for power-factor correction? (3) Are you aware that series capacitors would cause a phase-shift. (4) Why are you asking? Further editing required.